# Why does some JavaScript require a webserver?

Tags: javascript

Plain js can be written and rendered in a html file, or in a js file and then included in the html. But with my [Phaser.IO](https://phaser.io/) project, in order to get it to work I have to start a local web server. Why is this? Is it because of its referencing based of / of a typical www root?

Comment: Copy&Paste from the "[Getting started](https://phaser.io/tutorials/getting-started-phaser3)" section of the linked site: _"Why do I need a local web server? Can't I just drag the html files onto my browser?"_ with an explanation for the _"why"_

Comment: If you want a real answer more specific to your particular situation, please include code that you've found only works on a webserver.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it because of its referencing based of / of a typical www root?

That's likely, yes. If you open an HTML file locally, you're using the `file:` pseudo-scheme. If you then have a relative URL starting with a `/`, that's going to the root of your filesystem. (If you're on Windows, the only things [waves hands] at the root are drives like `C:`.)